# How to do a Sub-menu without a new Acitivity? Android programming

Tags: java, android

This is my first question at stackoverflow :-). However, I've started to Android programming some weeks ago and now I have get into a problem that I will describe below.

Problem:
I have a background-image for the whole screen. Inside this LinearLayout I have another LinearLayout with Buttons inside. How can I (without to start a new activity) load another buttons and make the first buttons disappear. The Buttons have a drawable background-image assigned to the specific button.

Like: I have a menu; play, options and quit. When I for example click on Options, the Options should load, and the play-button, options-button and quit-button should disappear.

All I want to become is to remain the background-image without to create a new activity and always can load a bunch of new buttons depending on the button that was clicked on.

For now I have created a new activity for the new buttons that should appear for example: Exit -> Do you want to Exit? Yes or no., then I also have done so the new acitivty loads another xml-layout-resource file, with the same background as before. This is what I want to change to a smoother resolution.

Comment: new to SO. Accept and upvote your answers. that helps you to get a quick responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two buttons with your second layout. use `button1.setVisibility(View.GONE)` method to set the visibility of the button. check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))